# Java - solve simple array earthquake program

Tags: java, arrays

I have a home work problem like this:

The following data represent Richter Scale data for earthquakes. Write a program to calculate and print the average of any valid earthquake data.

Store the Richter values in an array of doubles named quakeLevels.

Unfortunately, your seismograph is known to sometimes produce unreliable readings (like the value of 10.1 in this example). So you decide to throw out the maximum and minimum readings.

Your program should do the following:

Declare and initialize the quakeLevels array using the following data.
**{ 5.6, 6.2, 4.0, 5.5, 5.7, 6.1,7.4, 8.5, 5.5, 6.3, 6.4, 2.1, 6.9, 4.3, 3.1, 7.0, 10.1 }**

Determine the maximum and minimum values in the array.
Compute the average of the array contents, excluding the maximum and minimum values.
Print the values in the array excluding the maximum and minimum values.
Print the average.

I *cannot* use the Math class, so that is why everything is written out to print max and min.

Here is my code so far:

```
 public class ARRAYminAndmax0RichterScale
    {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            double [] quakeLevels = { 5.6, 6.2, 4.0, 5.5, 5.7, 6.1 ,7.4, 8.5, 5.5, 6.3, 6.4, 2.1, 6.9, 4.3, 3.1, 7.0, 10.1};    
            double [] quakeLevelsNormalized = new double [(quakeLevels.length - 2)];
            int i;

            int minIndex = 0;  // start with 0th element as min
            for ( i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length; i++) {                 
                if (quakeLevels[i] < quakeLevels[minIndex]) {
                    minIndex = i;                        
                }                    
            }
            System.out.print("Min: " + quakeLevels[minIndex] + "    ");

            int maxIndex = 0;  // start with 0th element as max
            for ( i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length; i++) {                 
                if (quakeLevels[i] > quakeLevels[maxIndex]) {
                    maxIndex = i;                        
                }                    
            }

            System.out.println("Max: " + quakeLevels[maxIndex]);                
           System.out.println("The Richter values, excluding the extrema, are as follows: ");   

            //make a new array excluding the max and min
            for ( i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length - 2; i++ ) {

                if(quakeLevels[i]!= minIndex && quakeLevels[i]!= maxIndex){
                    quakeLevelsNormalized[i] = quakeLevels[i];
                    System.out.printf("%6s\n", quakeLevelsNormalized[i] );
                }                    
            }

          //***THIS LOOP IS HERE TO HELP ME FIGURE OUT THE PROBLEM***
            for( i =0; i < quakeLevelsNormalized.length; i++){
                System.out.println("quakeLevelsNormalized["+i+"] = " + quakeLevelsNormalized[i]);
            }

            //find average of quakeLevelsNormalized
            double arrayTotal = 0;
            double average = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < quakeLevelsNormalized.length; i++) {

                arrayTotal = arrayTotal + quakeLevelsNormalized[ i ];

            }
            average = arrayTotal / quakeLevelsNormalized.length;

            //output

            System.out.println( quakeLevelsNormalized[i-1]);
            System.out.printf("%s%.1f\n","Average Quake Level = ", average);
        }

    }
```

### And I get the following output:

```
Min: 2.1    Max: 10.1

The Richter values, excluding the extrema, are as follows: 
   6.2
   4.0
   5.5
   5.7
   6.1
   7.4
   8.5
   5.5
   6.3
   6.4
   2.1
   6.9
   4.3
   3.1
quakeLevelsNormalized[0] = 0.0
quakeLevelsNormalized[1] = 6.2
quakeLevelsNormalized[2] = 4.0
quakeLevelsNormalized[3] = 5.5
quakeLevelsNormalized[4] = 5.7
quakeLevelsNormalized[5] = 6.1
quakeLevelsNormalized[6] = 7.4
quakeLevelsNormalized[7] = 8.5
quakeLevelsNormalized[8] = 5.5
quakeLevelsNormalized[9] = 6.3
quakeLevelsNormalized[10] = 6.4
quakeLevelsNormalized[11] = 2.1
quakeLevelsNormalized[12] = 6.9
quakeLevelsNormalized[13] = 4.3
quakeLevelsNormalized[14] = 3.1
3.1
Average Quake Level = 5.2
```

## Problem

So this is obviously not what it is supposed to look like. Why does it give me the extra 3.1 on the end? And it only has 14 elements, when it is supposed to have [18 minus the two extremes]? I'm a beginner programmer- and I *greatly* appreciate any and all help!!

Comment: Only a debugger can solve this problem.

Comment: Imposssible to edit your post, you should fix some issues, code missing and so on.

Comment: Is there a reason you are starting some of your `for` loops at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: In java array indexes start from 0 but i can see in your for loops you are doing int i = 1 .Are you sure you want to start form 2nd element?
And a  suggestion try to debug your program any time it does something unexpected.It will improve your understanding and help you solve your problems.

Comment: I think he does that as he assumed that initial min and max are the first element of the array, when fiding min and max

Comment: As usual SO is nice, as the accepted answer is the one just taking all the comments from other and putting them in an extra snippet of code.

Comment: @JeremyD I may be interpreting your last comment in the wrong way, but it seems like you are snidely implying that your answer is best and the reason I chose the one I did was because I could just copy it. I apologize profusely if this is not what you intended to say. But if it is, your assumption was incorrect and quite rude.

Comment: @JeremyD Your answer was not the most helpful because we have not done ArrayLists yet in my class. (Obviously, you couldnt have known this, but all the same that is part of the reason why).  I already commented my reasoning behind iterating on `0...length-2`, so that part wasnt helpful either. I sincerely do appreciate the time you took to try to answer my question though. :-)

Comment: @ReneaS.No I don't imply that my answer was the best. My answer is not the best as it used ArrayList, and it is not explanatory enough.

Comment: @JeremyD Okay. By the way, I do agree with you that explained answers are always best! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't even need the `quakeLevelsNormalized` array.
Here my solution, anyway this logic could be improved:

```
public class ARRAYminAndmax0RichterScale {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] quakeLevels = { 5.6, 6.2, 4.0, 5.5, 5.7, 6.1, 7.4, 8.5, 5.5,
                6.3, 6.4, 2.1, 6.9, 4.3, 3.1, 7.0, 10.1 };
        int i;
        int minIndex = 0; // start with 0th element as min
        for (i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length; i++) {
            if (quakeLevels[i] < quakeLevels[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Min: " + quakeLevels[minIndex] + "    ");
        int maxIndex = 0; // start with 0th element as max
        for (i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length; i++) {
            if (quakeLevels[i] > quakeLevels[maxIndex]) {
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Max: " + quakeLevels[maxIndex]);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Richter values, excluding the extrema, are as follows: ");
        double arrayTotal = 0;
        // make a new array excluding the max and min
        for (i = 0; i < quakeLevels.length; i++) {
            if (i != minIndex && i != maxIndex) {
                System.out.printf("%6s\n", quakeLevels[i]);
                arrayTotal += quakeLevels[i];
            }
        }
        double average = arrayTotal / (quakeLevels.length - 2);
        // output
        System.out.printf("%s%.1f\n", "Average Quake Level = ", average);
    }

}
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great! Would you mind explaining a little bit why I don't need that extra array?

Comment: I don't think giving the answer like that is good ithout explanation. He will just copy it and not even understand why.

Comment: @JeremyD I think you are right, yesterday I was in an hurry and I just wrote down my solution.

Comment: @ReneaS. I have simply choosen not to use an extra array because of your requirements. In the first part of your code you correctly found the index of the max and min value. After that, using the 3rd for loop, I just printed out the values I needed (excluding those with max and min index) and, at the same time, I accumulated the values into the arrayTotal variable in order to calculate the average value, as required. Hope I was clear, if not, please make questions and I will surely answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a mistake in comparisons.

if(quakeLevels[i]!= minIndex && quakeLevels[i]!= maxIndex)

In this line, you ask if the VALUE at index i is the same as the min/max index. This is not accurate to what you desire, youll want to compare i with maxIndex and minIndex directly.

Comment: do you mean like this?  for ( i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length - 2; i++ ) {
              
                if(i!= minIndex && i!= maxIndex){
                    quakeLevelsNormalized[i] = quakeLevels[i];
                    System.out.printf("%6s\n", quakeLevelsNormalized[i] );
            
                }
                
            }

Comment: Yes, exactly. i should not be passed into the array. Passing it into the array gets a quake value, when the original poster intends to compare the index.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible methods to help you:

```
    /**
     * Get the largest number in the array
     */
    public double getMax(double[] array) {
            double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            for (double n : array) {
                    if (n > max) max = n;
            }
            return max;
    }

    /**
     * Get the smallest number in the array
     */
    public double getMin(double[] array) {
            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (double n : array) {
                    if (n < min) min = n;
            }
            return min;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified number from the array, return a new array with the number removed
     */
    public double[] removeFromArray(double[] array, double number) {
            int count = 0;
            for (double n : array) {
                    if (n==number) count++;
            }
            double[] result = new double[array.length - count];
            int index = 0;
            for (double n : array) {
                    if (n!=number) result[index++] = n;
            }
            return result;
    }

    /**
     * Work out the mean of all the numbers in an array
     */
    public double averageOfArray(double[] array) {
            double total = 0;
            for (double n : array) {
                    total += n;
            }
            return total / array.length;
    }
```

Comment: We just learned how to do this, so that is why I haven't gone this way in my program. But thank you so much for your time/response because it enabled me to see how I could use top-down design in my program. So thanks for helping me learn!!

Comment: No worries. Top-down design is always best - a complicated problem is nothing more than a number of simple problems put together.

Answer (score 0):

There are few areas you can improve your code. For finding minimum and maximum you can use the collections method:

```
int minIndex = quakeLevels.indexOf(Collections.min(quakeLevels));
int maxIndex = quakeLevels.indexOf(Collections.max(quakeLevels));
```

and your main problem is in the following line.

```
**//make a new array excluding the max and min
            for ( i = 1; i < quakeLevels.length - 2; i++ )**
```

why it is `quakeLevels.length - 2`, it should be `quakeLevels.length`. and also verify  `i = 1;` or  `i = 0;` need to be used in for loops.

and remove the following line

```
System.out.println( quakeLevelsNormalized[i-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! it is quakeLevels.length - 2 because the original array is 18 elements long, so I thought that this new array should have two elements less than 18, since I am not including the max and min? In other words the new array is the same as quakeLevels, but excluding the max and min.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not allowed to use Collection types, right?

Try splitting the problem down into it's component parts and doing them one by one.

1) Only use the valid data:  you could do this by looping through the array and checking each element in turn to see if it's <=0 or >=10.  If it's valid, stick it in another array, if it's not, ignore it.

2) Calculate the max and min values: you've done this one!  Store the indexes for the next bit

3) Calculate the average: loop through the values adding them up and printing them out as you go along, skipping the min and max you stored from above

Check each part is working before doing the next, it'll be easier for you to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(quakeLevels[i]!= minIndex && quakeLevels[i]!= maxIndex) {
           quakeLevelsNormalized[i] = quakeLevels[i];
           System.out.printf("%6s\n", quakeLevelsNormalized[i] );
}
```

You should compare the index, not the values associated to the minIndex and maxIndex.

Also, why do you do iterate on `0...length-2`, you should just iterate on `0.. length-1` and check that the index is different than `minIndex` and `maxIndex`

This : `arrayTotal = arrayTotal + quakeLevelsNormalized[ i ]` can be simplified as

```
arrayTotal += quakeLevelsNormalized[i]
```

If you can use an ArrayList for the normalized levels datastructure, you should, you don't have to care about the index this way.

You will just do:

```
if ((i != minIndex) && (i != maxIndex)) {
    normalized.add(quakeLevels[i])
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the calculation of the `quakeLevelsNormalized` array. Check this

```
//you need another index variable for 'quakeLevelsNormalized'
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < quakeLevels.length; i++) {

    //check the index, not the value, you have this wrong in your code
    //if(quakeLevels[i]!= minIndex && quakeLevels[i]!= maxIndex){
    if (i != minIndex && i != maxIndex) {
        quakeLevelsNormalized[j] = quakeLevels[i];
        System.out.printf("%6s\n", quakeLevelsNormalized[j]);

        //increment the index of 'quakeLevelsNormalized' array
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Okay now,

It is correct, except for that fact that the values at index 13 and 14 are 0.0
`quakeLevelsNormalized[0] = 6.2`
`quakeLevelsNormalized[1] = 4.0`
`...`

`quakeLevelsNormalized[13] = 0.0`
`quakeLevelsNormalized[14] = 0.0`

This makes sense that I would have two values that are 0.0, but` shouldn't they be at a different(as in higher) index, considering the fact that the original array had
18 elements? So I think this one should have 16?